# Linux Terminal jumps back to first character of line unexpectedly

Tags: terminal

I'm currently following a Youtube tutorial but when I try to type out the following command

```
cat ip.txt | grep "64 bytes" | cut .....
```

The terminal returns me to the beginning of the line when I type the first `c` in `cut`.
I will add a gif so you can understand better what I mean.

[image]

It automatically jumps to the first character of the line and overtypes what I've already written unless I do CTRL + C. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

You probably resized the width of the terminal while editing a file. When you finished editing it the shell's idea of the terminal width remained unchanged.

Next time this happens, run this command

```
kill -WINCH $$
```

It tells the shell to recheck the current terminal window size (`WINCH` stands for WINdow CHange, and it sends a signal with this message to the current process, `$$`)